# Controller doesn't seem to be registered

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I'm attempting to get `ngRoute` to work for the first time by myself.

However I'm hitting a `Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]` when attempting to register my controller.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="resources/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-div" class="flex">
        <div class="flex header">
            <img id="header-img-left" src="resources/img/WSC.png" />
            <img id="header-img-right" src="resources/img/StobartRail.png" />
        </div>
        <!-- body -->
        <div ng-app="kioskApp" id="questions-div">
            <div ng-view></div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/homeController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it references two `.js` files, one being the module and the second being the `homeController`.

The module simply sets up the routes:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('kioskApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                controller: "../../app/components/homeController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "../../app/home/home.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/login", {
                controller: "../../app/components/loginController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "../../app/home/login.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
        });

})();
```

My .html gets picked up fine as I can see various elements on that file in my `ng-view`. But for some reason my controller doesn't seem to be registered...

I can't find any problems with the `homeController`:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module('kioskApp')
        .controller('homeController', homeController);

    function homeController() {
        let vm = this;

        vm.placeholder = [{ id: 10 }, { id: 11 }];

    };
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when binding controllers to `routes`, there is no need for the file path.
refer the below example:

```
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "homeController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "../../app/home/home.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/login", {
            controller: "loginController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "../../app/home/login.html"
        });
```

Comment: F**k my life... I've been looking at this screen for way too long... Cheers <3

Comment: @geostocker angularjs will search for controller you registered by it's name.  :)

Answer (score 0):

there's an error when you specify the controller, instead of the path to the file you have to specify the name.

this should be the correct syntax

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '../../app/home/login.html',
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route config just use the controller name instead of controller path.
Like :

```
 $routeProvider.when("/", {
       controller: "homeController",
       controllerAs: "vm",
       templateUrl: "../../app/home/home.html"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the controller field to the name of the controller, not the path.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

> controller – {(string|Function)=} – Controller fn that should be
>   associated with newly created scope or the name of a registered
>   controller if passed as a string.